# How to make the decimal work in calculator p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

So I am building a calculator using only p5.js. I have made it all function properly exept from one button. The decimal point. I have done something on the decimal in my code but it doesn't really work like I want it. Does anyone know how to make this feature work. Help is hghly appreciated. Thank you.

```
let number = 0;
let number1 = 0;
let operation = "";

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  let one = createButton('1');
  one.mousePressed(clickedOne);
  let two = createButton('2');
  two.mousePressed(clickedTwo);
  let three = createButton('3');
  three.mousePressed(clickedThree);
  let four = createButton('4');
  four.mousePressed(clickedFour);
  let five = createButton('5');
  five.mousePressed(clickedFive);
  let six = createButton('6');
  six.mousePressed(clickedSix);
  let seven = createButton('7');
  seven.mousePressed(clickedSeven);
  let eight = createButton('8');
  eight.mousePressed(clickedEight);
  let nine = createButton('9');
  nine.mousePressed(clickedNine);
  let zero = createButton('0');
  zero.mousePressed(clickedZero);
  let equals = createButton('=');
  equals.mousePressed(pressedEquals);
  let clear = createButton('AC');
  clear.mousePressed(clickedClear);
  let divide = createButton('÷');
  divide.mousePressed(clickedDivide);
  let multiply = createButton('x');
  multiply.mousePressed(clickedMultiply);
  let add = createButton('+');
  add.mousePressed(clickedAdd);
  let minus = createButton('-');
  minus.mousePressed(clickedMinus);
  let decimal = createButton('.');
  decimal.mousePressed(clickedDecimal);
  one.position(100, 150);
  one.size(45, 45);
  two.position(144, 150);
  two.size(45, 45);
  four.position(100, 194);
  four.size(45, 45);
  six.position(188, 194);
  six.size(45, 45);
  three.position(188, 150);
  three.size(45, 45);
  five.position(144, 194);
  five.size(45, 45);
  seven.position(100, 238);
  seven.size(45, 45);
  eight.position(144, 238);
  eight.size(45, 45);
  nine.position(188, 238);
  nine.size(45, 45);
  zero.position(100, 282);
  zero.size(45, 45);
  equals.position(188, 282);
  equals.size(45, 45);
  divide.position(232, 150);
  divide.size(45, 45);
  multiply.position(232, 194);
  multiply.size(45, 45);
  add.position(232, 238);
  add.size(45, 45);
  minus.position(232, 282);
  minus.size(45, 45);
  clear.position(100, 106);
  clear.size(177, 45);
  decimal.position(144, 282);
  decimal.size(45, 45);

}

function clickedOne() {
  number = number * 10 + 1;
}

function clickedTwo() {
  number = number * 10 + 2;
}

function clickedThree() {
  number = number * 10 + 3;
}

function clickedFour() {
  number = number * 10 + 4;
}

function clickedFive() {
  number = number * 10 + 5;
}

function clickedSix() {
  number = number * 10 + 6;
}

function clickedSeven() {
  number = number * 10 + 7;
}

function clickedEight() {
  number = number * 10 + 8;
}

function clickedNine() {
  number = number * 10 + 9;
}

function clickedZero() {
  number = number * 10 + 0;
}

function clickedDivide() {
  number1 = number;
  number = 0;
  operation = "÷";
}

function clickedMultiply() {
  number1 = number;
  number = 0;
  operation = "x";
}

function clickedAdd() {
  number1 = number;
  number = 0;
  operation = "+";
}

function clickedMinus() {
  number1 = number;
  number = 0;
  operation = "-";
}

function clickedClear() {
  number = 0;
  number1 = 0;
  operation = ""
}

function clickedDecimal() {
  number = number + 0.0 ;
}

function pressedEquals() {
  if (operation === "+") {
        number = number1 + number;
    } else if (operation === "-") {
        number = number1 - number;
    } else if (operation === "x") {
        number = number1 * number
    } if (operation === "÷") {
        number = number1 / number
    }
  operation = "";
}

function draw() {
  background(150);
  noStroke();
  fill(20, 255, 255, 30);
  rect(100, 53, 177, 54, 5);
  strokeWeight(6);
  stroke(0);
  noFill();
  rect(97, 50, 183, 280, 5);
  strokeWeight(1);
  stroke(0);
  fill(0);
  textSize(25);

    if (operation != "") {
        let display = number1 + " " + operation + " " + number;
        text(display, 110, 100);
    } else {
        text(number, 110, 100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you enter the digits/symbols as strings?
As I can see, you're already doing that for the operators. Just enter them as strings and evaluate the expression when required. If you wish to display the live result of the expression all the time, just convert and interpret the string each time in draw.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is not the easiest language when it comes to math, especially numbers.

While your idea of adding a decimal number with an integer would have been the correct idea in a strongly typed language such as C++ (`0.0 + 1` would be equal to `0.0` as double) , Javascript only has a `Number` type that stores, well, numbers.

Consider the following code

```js
let x = 9.0;
let y = 9.2;
console.log(x);
console.log(y);
```

The output would be

> 9
>   9.2

I think you see what I mean with that, Javascript will only show decimal places if it's useful to do so, or at least when *it* thinks it's useful.

You have several work-around possibilities:

- Use [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) in your display
- Do nothing until the user actually adds a decimal number
- When the user clicks on the decimal point, you store a flag somewhere that the display should be decimal (and combine that with the first possibility)